# Cannot execute, insert or update in bluemix DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Since today morning, every time I try to do an Insert or Update statement over a DB2 Bluemix base, it throws the following error:

```
The transaction log for the database is full... SQLCODE=-964, SQLSTATE=57011, DRIVER=4.19.56*
```

It happens to many bases I have, no matter if it is an entry plan, or a paid base plan, and also in many environments. I've tried to do it by console, and through JDBC (which throws ExceptionConfig: cannot perform the operation).
Is it a general problem?

Comment: Most likely there are stuck transactions holding the active transaction log(s) opened.  You can either force off those idle/stuck connections (with risk of data loss), or dynamically increase the secondary-logging capacity (db cfg logsecond parameter) if the filesystem has enough free space. But eventually you will need to identify and permanently resolve the jobs that are failing to commit.

Comment: I didn't mention that it started happening today, in all databases at the same time, and those bases are different instances and different plans of DB2/DashDB. So, i think that is kind unlikely. Thanks anyway, i will try it while i wait for more alternatives.

Comment: If the app-server(s) had all been started around the same time, a build-up can happen. Just ask DB2 for the connection-id holding the oldest transaction, then identify when was the most recent commit on that connection.  That will prove it.